# Apartment entry knob issue

Tags: doors, lock

I have been having issues with my apartment door not opening when I turn the knob. The knob is very loose and as a result, it is able to move left and right. Although functionally, turning to the right is the only way that latch bolt moves inward to the faceplate, allowing the door to open. Typically the door works, but is very finicky. Today it is simply not working. The latch bolt is stuck and is not moving inward to the faceplate.

If I am outside of the door, I can use the key (Mul-T-Lock 006C) and turn it to the right (as in the video) which allows the latch bolt to move inward. Once I do this, I can go back to the inside door knob and turn it, and the latch bolt works properly.

However, upon closing the door fully (from the inside), I now cannot get the door knob to trigger the latch bolt at all to open up the door, meaning I am locked in my apartment and cannot get out unless someone from the outside opens with the key (see video). You can also notice in the video that on the lock body, where the mounting spring on the knob inserts, it is quite loose. Not sure if this is an issue. I am not using the deadbolt at all, so this is only an issue with knob trigger latch bolt.

My question is, do I need to replace the whole door entry knob or is there a way to fix this?

Video: https://youtu.be/GRksbiEW5v0

I used certain terms above that seem to differ from diagrams, so I've attached the diagram I was looking at for clarity of parts I'm referencing.

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image]

Comment: Probably the mechanism inside the lock body is worn out and needs to be replaced. you should be able to retain the existing external hardware, lockset, and keys.

Comment: are you renting your apartment?

Comment: yes, and i'm sure my landlord would have someone come fix it, however, based on the experience of renting for 10 years, I find it best to present the issue with the potential problem/solution so it actually gets fixed properly asap. plus, it's good i'm educating myself on door mechanisms now - learning experience.

Comment: The lock on my old workplace was the exact same. if you don't use the deadbolt, anyone can open that door from the outside with a credit card in seconds. The slope translates forward energy into retraction energy, no hooking required. All that's protecting you is the virtually-cosmetic door stop and tight margins, neither of which are secure. You can do that yourself if you can't get in, might be easier in fact than messing with the knob.

Comment: I agree, you could easily get in that way. The issue right now is leaving the apartment. If I close the door, the latch bolt doesn't turn properly when the knob is turned, meaning I can't exit. Going into the apt right now with a key is no issue.